# Dealing with non-option arguments in getopt before options are checked

Tags: c, unix, getopt

I am writing a program and I want to get the non-option arguments before checking the flags.

For example, if the arguments are `./a.out -a -b 50 filename`

I want to use `filename` and then do `task_a()` and/or `task_b()`depending on the flags. `filename` can be any argument in `argv[]`

```
int opt;
float value;
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "ab:")) != -1)
    case 'a':
        task_a(filename);
        break;
    case 'b':
         value = atof(optarg);
         task_b(filename, value);
         break;
```

So basically I need to extract `filename` before using it in my tasks. How can I implement this?

Comment: If you are on Linux, consider reading the [documentation of GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), in particular its section [§25 The Basic Program/System Interface](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Basics.html) and [getopt(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt_long.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

getopt will pass you the command line arguments in the order that it finds them on the command line.   This is generally NOT the order that you want to process them.

Instead, have your program set its options first before performing the operations - so something like ( given #include <stdbool.h> ) :

```
// Set the defaults
bool doTaskA = false;
book doTaskB = false;
float brightness = -1;

int opt;
float value;
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "ab:")) != -1) {
    case 'a':
    doTaskA = true;
    break;
case 'b':
     doTaskB = true;
     brightness = atof(optarg);
     break;
}

filename = ....,,

if (doTaskA) {
      task_a(filename);
}

if (doTaskB) {
    task_b(filename, brightness);
}
```

I chose the name “brightness” as a meaningful attribute name - naturally you should choose your own.   As good practice, do NOT name your variables “optionA” or some such - variable names should describe what they ARE, not the specific implementation details.

Always imagine that your options can change letters over time (what is now option “a” might become option “R” in six months time) - such changes should not affect anything except the “getopt” arguments and “case” statements.

EDITED TO CHANGE :
I originally wrote this with “if (brightness >= 0.0)”, but decided that in general a separate doTaskB variable is cleaner, more explicit approach that does not limit the possible values of the argument.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand this but my requirement also extends to the fact where the tasks should be done in the order that the arguments are given in `argv`. And plus there are about 10 tasks that may need to be done according to the number of flags

Comment: @Wind_Fire Glad to help.   Whatever the requirements, I would ALWAYS separate the parsing of the command line from the program doing its stuff.   They are two separate distinct phases of the program execution - 1) figure out what the user wants to do, then 2) do it.   Don’t mix them.   So the output of phase 1 is a structure detailing everything that the program is to do and what to do it with.   So if order is important, then that order should be in that structure.  It really will pay dividends as cleaner more explicit code that is easily maintainable as requirements change in future.